# Passing emails in utm strings

Tags: javascript, email, url, google-analytics, query-string

It seems that Google doesn't like passing emails in plain text in the query string parameters (they contacted the owners of the website mentioning to not pass the emails in plain text in query string parameters).

We asked the support if encoding the emails in base64 (`btoa("plain@te.xt)`) would help. Their answer was very generic mentioning that we can replace the emails with user ids (leaving a link to the [Identifier page from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier)).

Since the answers from Google are not very clear, I'm just wondering what is the specific issue with passing the emails.

Specifically, is the problem the fact we are sending the emails in plain text (e.g. `site.com/foo?email=some@email.com`)?
If they are base64 encoded, would that help in anyway (since anyone can decode them)?

If encoding them in base64, would encrypting/decrypting them using a key work better?

---

The usage of the emails is for tracking the user using an external service:

```
var email = getTheEmailFromTheUrl()
thatExternalService.identify(email)
```

Comment: did you try `encodeURIComponent` while passing email as parameter?

Comment: @AbhishekNair How would that help in the current context? The question is if Google doesn't like the emails in the urls just because they are in plain text and if encoding or encrypting would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue is that emails are by definition personally identifiable data. Storing this in GA is a violation of Googles terms of service (and depending on your legislation it might be a violation of local laws).

See the [support page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en), specifically:

> Google policies mandate that no data be passed to Google that Google
>   could use or recognize as personally identifiable information (PII).
>   **PII includes, but is not limited to, information such as email
>   addresses**, personal mobile numbers, and social security numbers

and for the question of hashing:

> Hashed and salted PII You can send Google Analytics an encrypted
>   identifier or custom dimension that is based on PII, as long as you
>   use the proper encryption level. Google has a minimum hashing
>   requirement of SHA256 and strongly recommends the use of a salt, with
>   a minimum of 8 characters. Notwithstanding any of the foregoing, you
>   may not send Google Analytics encrypted Protected Health Information
>   (as defined under HIPAA), even if it is hashed or salted.

If you are in Europe please note that under the new privacy directive even a hashed email would be PII (since you can resolve it using an external system like a CRM), which is basically your use case (one issue is that you cannot remove PII from GA on request).

In short, this is not a technical thing, but a legal matter.

Comment: To be honest, this is a much clearer answer than the one from Google, but I'm still not sure what the solution is in our case. We don't really send the PII to Google Analytics (maybe they collect them automatically?). This website tracks the users' activity using Mixpanel (`thatExternalService`). Assuming we don't send the PII to Google, is it fine to keep the emails in the url to allow tracking via Mixpanel? Is it only Google restricting us to send them PII or the EU telling us to not track users even using Mixpanel? I'm still a little bit confused.

Comment: Or is it because the url is tracked via GA? Google Remarketing Tag is used too, could it be they collect these urls as well?

Comment: Not a lawyer, but if your users have agreed that their mail address is stored, and if mixpanel allows to delete the data on request, then mixpanel should be fine. However if you do not store the data in any Google software then I do not know what their specific complaint is.

Comment: My guess is that they detected the emails in the urls themselves (which are probably stored somewhere in GA). Maybe a solution would be to remove the querystring params before calling the GA functions.

Comment: The inescapable Simo Ahava has a nice article on how to remove PII from analytics requests: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/remove-pii-google-analytics-hits/